# How to compute an inverse suffix array $ISA$ from a suffix array $SA$ efficiently?

Tags: strings, suffix-array

I cannot help but wonder: how to compute an inverse of a suffix array, preferably in linear time?

For $ISA$, it holds that $ISA[SA[i]] = i$.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to define what you mean by the "inverse" of a suffix array.  You might also make this useful and interesting for others by providing some motivation why this is a useful or relevant task.

Comment: @D.W. Will do, but tomorrow. (Now tired.)